# Using UDF for value of a column postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, user-defined-functions

Let's say I already have 2 table with movies and their ratings.

```
CREATE TABLE public.movies (
movieid int4 NOT NULL,
averagerating float4 NULL,
title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
"year" int4 NULL,
CONSTRAINT movies_pkey PRIMARY KEY (movieid)
);

CREATE TABLE public.ratings (
movie_id int4 NOT NULL,
user_id int4 NOT NULL,
rating float4 NOT NULL,
timestmp varchar(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ratings_pkey PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, user_id),
CONSTRAINT fk44trpo3u915t27ybt03ib4h0o FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movies(movieid),
CONSTRAINT fk7ymub8kd95i2xlklgole3i684 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES usrs(userid)
);
```

For now column **averagerating** in **movies** is empty everywhere. I want to attach my UDF **average_movie_rating** to this column

Something like `update movies set averagerating = average_movie_rating(movies.movieid)`

This function:

```
create or replace function average_movie_rating(movieid integer)
returns float8 as $averagerating$
declare 
averagerating float8;
begin
select avg(r.rating) into averagerating from ratings r where r.movie_id = $1;
return averagerating;
end
$averagerating$ language plpgsql;
```

Would it be possible and if yes, how do I pass this **movieid** to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless required for performance reasons, you should calculate that value when you select from the database. If you have to persist it, use a trigger on `ratings` that modifies `movies`.